# SQL CICD issue on azure devops classic editor

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

While we run pipeline using our self-hosted agent, we are getting the below issue.

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(507,5): Error MSB4181: The “SqlBuildTask” task returned false but did not log an error.
```

---

While we run the pipeline on a Microsoft hosted agent, the pipeline is successful. If the build is successful using Microsoft hosted agent, the CD is failing with this below error.

```
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
```

I am expecting the solution for the issue and successful deployment into respective environment.

Comment: For the self-hosted agent error, you can compare the logs to find the difference between self-hosted agent and Microsoft hosted agent. To see more detailed logs, you can add a variable named `system.debug` and set its value to `true`.

Comment: For the CD issue, maybe you can refer [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/284618/the-database-platform-service-with-type-microsoft).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the below fix for me when the build on the Windows 2019 build server was failing. When I published this locally to the database, error was very explicit to change the Visual studio DB project target platform, but on the build server it was cryptic ("[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(507,5): Error MSB4181: The “SqlBuildTask” task returned false but did not log an error")

Changing the Target platform under database project properties and building it again using the ADO build pipeline solved the issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that you installed SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio on your build agent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I installed SQL server data tools, and i still end up with below error in pipeline

 ##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(507,5): Error MSB4181: The “SqlBuildTask” task returned false but did not log an error.